# Is there a formula for generating all positive integers that cannot be written as a linear combination over nonnegative integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b \in\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $a \leq b$. We know that when $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then the largest integer that cannot be written as $am+bn$ for some nonnegative integers $m$ and $n$ not both zero is $ab-a-b$ (this number is typically called the Frobenius or McNugget number).

Does anyone happen to know if there is a formula for generating all positive integers $< ab-a-b$ that cannot be expressed as $am+bn$, where $m$ and $n$ are nonnegative integers not both zero, assuming that they exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Bezout's identity, you find integers $u,v$ with $ua+vb=1$.
Then all ways to write $n$ as linear combination of $a,b$ are of the form
$$ n=(nu-kb)a+(nv+ka)b.$$
So the question is whether there exists $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that both $nu-kb\ge0$ and $nv+ka\ge0$, i.e.,
$$ nbv\le kab\le nau.$$
In other words, you are looking for those other $n$ with
$$ \left\lceil\frac{nv}{a}\right\rceil>\left\lfloor\frac{nu}{b}\right\rfloor$$